# Working with paths from [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]

Tags: objective-c, directory, path, nsbundle

I'm sure it's a very basic problem, but I'm having trouble finding anything about it.

Say I've got my app in a folder, in some more folders, like this:

- MainFolder > SecondaryFolder > AppBundle.app > all the stuff

Then, what I want to do is access a file that is in the "MainFolder". I know I can get the path of the AppBundle by using:

> NSLog(@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]);

What I'm uncertain about is how to get the path of the "MainFolder".

Any pointers would be great!

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'd use `-[NSString stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]` twice.

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *secondParentPath = [[bundlePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 5):

I use:
`NSString *mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];`

Comment: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]` gives you the path of the bundle-file itself, if you want the path inside the bundle, the contents, then it is `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]`