# NSData writeToFile on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdata, writetofile

I think the error is with the path, but I got the code (slightly modified) off a tutorial online for a Mac App, and it worked fine.  It wrote to `client_state.xml` (in the build folder).  However on my iphone navigation based app, it compiles and runs fine.  And if I `NSLog` the data or the document I get the corresponding information, I just can't find the `.xml` file anywhere.

```
//doc_client is a DDXMLDocument file from kissXML.  The XMLData message returns the NSData
//from the document
NSData *xmlD = [doc_client XMLData];
[xmlD writeToFile:@"client_state.xml" atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file path is relative to the current working directory of your app; if the application is sandboxed and the current directory is outside the app bundle, the `writeToFile:atomically:` method will fail.

Try providing an absolute path constructed [dynamically based on the main bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949992/working-with-paths-from-nsbundle-mainbundle-resourcepath).

Comment: This worked perfectly.  (I can't flag it as the right answer for 5 more minutes, but I will).