# Why this Objective-C code won't play an AVPlayerViewController video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

[image]Both are in viewDidLoad(). 
What's wrong with this objective-c source file?
The swift version works like a charm...
Xcode ver. 8.2  iOS 10

Swift (OK):

```
        let path : String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "charlie", ofType: "mp4")!
        let movieurl : URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let movie : AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        movie.view.frame = self.view.bounds

        let player : AVPlayer = AVPlayer(url: movieurl)
        movie.player = player

        self.view.addSubview(movie.view)
        player.play()
```

Objective-C (Won't show/play the video):

```
        AVPlayerViewController* movie;
        AVPlayer* player;

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
            pathForResource:@"charlie" ofType:@"mp4"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path] ;

        movie = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        movie.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];

        [movie setPlayer:player];
        [self.view addSubview:movie.view];

        [player play];
```

Comment: The code probably didn't find the video. Did you try using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949992/working-with-paths-from-nsbundle-mainbundle-resourcepath to fix the bundlepath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@import AVKit;
@import AVFoundation;
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayer *avPlayer; 
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController* avPlayerView;


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Video1" ofType:@"mp4"];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];

AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
[avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
self.avPlayerView = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
self.avPlayerView.view.frame = self.view.bounds; 
[self.avPlayerView setPlayer:_avPlayer]; 
[self.view addSubview:_avPlayerView.view]; 

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == avPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");
        } else if (avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Ready to Play");
        } else if (avPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");
        }
    }
}

-(IBAction) BtnPlay:(id)sender {
    [avPlayer play];
}

-(IBAction) BtnPause:(id)sender {
    [avPlayer pause];
}
```

**Try my code . if any issue with my code put comment . 
Thank You. 
Happy Coding.**

Comment: Yes it worked with online videos, but I couldn't get it to work with local videos (I got just a blank screen). And still would like to know what's wrong with the code of the question... Thanks anyway.

Comment: #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> did you use this framework @huse

Comment: use a property not a local pointer for  AVPlayer* player i suspect it get  released as soon as allocated

Comment: @LucaRocchi If that was the case it would probably crash rather then just not play the video?

Comment: Sorry for the late response (short winter vacation). I am going to try your suggestions right now.

Comment: @huse ok try it and happy new year .

Comment: @Himanshu Moradiya At least I can now hear the video but got only a white screen... I'm going to find out what am I doing wrong...

Comment: brother try one thing that create a frame of controller then try i did not use to give frame so .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  (Happy new year!) Now it's working. 
I was missing the AVPlayerViewController stuff. 
I will mark your answer as correct but could you please add the following to your answer so it will help other people? Thanks.     

  property (nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController* avPlayerView;  
 
 _avPlayerView = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
 _avPlayerView.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
 [_avPlayerView setPlayer:_avPlayer];
 [self.view addSubview:_avPlayerView.view];

 [_avPlayer play];

Comment: @huse done it bro. now you can approve and give vote. happy coding,

Comment: i have applied this but nothing is happening . player view just appear but not playing the song  . i am playing the mp3 song with URL .

Comment: @Moxarth mp3 file also pay in this player did you show your code

Answer (score 0):

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
            pathForResource:@"charlie" ofType:@"mp4"];

Try

Using [NSURL **fileURLWithPath**:path] instead of  [NSURL **URLWithString**:path]

[NSURL fileURLWithPath]

Or

[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"charlie" withExtension:@"mp4"]

Comment: i have applied this but nothing is happening . player view just appear but not playing the song . i am playing the mp3 song with URL .