# AVPlayer crashes after multiple time play video from local directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

When i click my **local video** url and present Viewcontroller and Play video in AVPlayer.Play 14-15 times and Player crash.[Avplayer showing like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHqBj.png)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [self PlayVideoinPlayer:_videoURL];
}

-(void)PlayVideoinPlayer:(NSString *)URL
{
      NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:URL];

     _Avcontroller=[[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
      asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];
     anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
     _avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
     [_avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
     self.Avcontroller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
     [self.Avcontroller setPlayer:_avPlayer];
    _Avcontroller.videoGravity=AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
     [self.view addSubview:self.Avcontroller.view];
     [self.view addSubview:self.Avcontroller.view];
     [_avPlayer play];

    CMTime interval = CMTimeMake(1, 1800);
   __strong __typeof(self) weakself = self;
    playbackObserver = [_avPlayer    addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock: ^(CMTime time) {
    CMTime endTime = CMTimeConvertScale  (_avPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration, _avPlayer.currentTime.timescale, kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundHalfAwayFromZero);
    if (CMTimeCompare(endTime, kCMTimeZero) != 0)
    {
        // double normalizedTime = (double) avPlayer.currentTime.value / (double) endTime.value;
        //NSLog(@"--------->>>>%@",playbackObserver);
    }
    int CurrentSecond=[[weakself getStringFromCMTime:_avPlayer.currentTime] intValue];
   _avPlayer.rate=1.0f;

 }
```

Anyone have solution.? Please help me.Thanks

Comment: did you set all time avplayerviewcontroller frame. >?

Comment: Yes,
avPlayer=[AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
Avcontroller=[[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
Avcontroller.player=avPlayer;
Avcontroller.view.frame=self.view.frame;
Avcontroller.videoGravity=AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill; [self.view addSubview:_Avcontroller.view];

Comment: Brother show your full code

Comment: Dear this is whole code and click url directly present viewcontroller and player [self.view addSubview:_Avcontroller.view]; and start.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41359054/6656894 refer this answer

Comment: Thanks for reply dear, but how to dismiss viewcontroller or where is 'Done' button avplayer.? i can add there 'Done' button.?

Comment: done button is default button of avplayerviewcontroller so its handle by it self you just refer my answer if query then put comment there and also read comment  in that answer

Comment: Anyone have solution.?

Comment: did you refer this question and answer carefully ?

Comment: i'm trying but not resolve. getting error player is blank with cross line on play icon.

Comment: brother did you must have to post your whole snap code stackoverflow.com/a/41359054/6656894  in this question same problem user face and its solve it

Comment: see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359004/why-this-objective-c-code-wont-play-an-avplayerviewcontroller-video/41359054#41359054